# What is the best approach to have some additional attributes of a User?

Tags: jhipster

We need to have some additional attributes such as photo # and so on of the User entity. Based on what we learned, it shall be done by adding an entity that has a 1-to-1 relationship with the User entity. There are some related classes of the User entity: UserDTO, AdminUserDTO, and ManagedUserVM. I guess that we also need to create a DTO and VM. But, a service class is a condition of DTO and Mapper while the User entity and the additional entity shall be viewed as a single entity in the system. What will be a suitable solution?